# SFML parsing event code

Tags: c++, parsing, events, sfml

I wan't to know how could I improve the way I handle the events in SFML :

So I have a function called processEvents() that has a switch for the events type, I also have a function for each types (like mousePressed, mouseReleased, keyPressed ...). And my problem is the size of those functions, because I also have an enum class for the states of the game, so in each function there is a switch for it and in each cases I do different things, the result is that mouseReleased for example is 341 lines long.

I want to know how could I parse better the events in order to reduce the size of the functions.

Comment: Split into multiple smaller functions?

Comment: Look into [Thor actions](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/tutorials/v2.0/actions.html)

Comment: Thank you, that looks interesting

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `std::vector<bool> down` and use for index the key code or mouse button (so one vector for keyboard and an other one for the mouse). Then, when event pressed is received you just do `down[event.key.code] = true` and when the released event is received you set it to `false`.

Comment: Better use `std::map` then, so you don't have to map all possible values, even if they're not used.

Comment: @Mario `std::unordered_map` would be better for that, but even better, considering the amount of simultaneously pressed keys is always low (even when someone's bashing their keyboard, it's likely < 30), a simple `std::vector<sf::Keyboard::Key>` with a linear lookup is better.

Comment: No, a std::map is slow to access. And std::vector<bool> is a template specialization, each boolean value takes only a bit in memory so thats okay :)

Answer (score 0):

You effectively want to decentralize the processing code. Enable various components to register a handler for an event at some 'sfml event-dispatcher'-object. This object's only job is to call the corresponding handlers (could be represented using a std::function) when an event arrives, without knowing what exactly that handler does.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how std::function works but I can learn :)